# Click event with transcript for jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, click, jwplayer

This is a small part of homework but I am currently stuck and have no idea what to do. The whole project was to create the JWplayer, match the video with the transcript, highlight phrases from the transcript in sync with the video, and be able to click on the phrases and have the video jump to it. I'm stuck on the last part.

```
$.fn.playerConnect = function(player){


    var transcriptElements = this;

    player.onTime(function(evt){



    return this.click(function(evt){ // where the action happens
    var i = 0;
    var startTime = parseFloat($(transcriptElements[i]).attr("data-start"));
             player.seek(startTime);

   });
};

})(jQuery);
```

This is the Html part of the project. As you will be able to tell, the phrases are separated into span's. So basically, the pseudocode is

for click event, return value of data-start,
seek value in video (player.seek)

```
 <div id="playerDiv">Video Will Appear Here</div>
  <div id="transcript"> <span class="words" data-start="10.099" data-dur="7"></span>
    <span class="words" data-start="17.869" data-dur="3.82">Hey this is
      Dwayne Johnson. While playing astronaut Chuck Baker in the film Planet</span>
    <span class="words" data-start="21.689" data-dur="0.701">51</span> <span
      class="words" data-start="22.39" data-dur="3.56">I gained a lot of
      respect for our nation's space program. NASA makes new</span> <span class="words"
      data-start="25.95" data-dur="1.35">discoveries about our universe</span>
    <span class="words" data-start="27.3" data-dur="4.11">every day but one
      of the coolest things about nasa is the technologies that</span> <span
      class="words" data-start="31.41" data-dur="1.55">it creates for
      exploring space</span> <span class="words" data-start="32.96" data-dur="3.739">are
      also improving life here on earth. NASA technologies can be found</span>
    <span class="words" data-start="36.699" data-dur="0.621">everywhere</span>
    <span class="words" data-start="37.32" data-dur="3.71">from the soles of
      the shoes to the freeze dried fruit in your cereal. These</span> <span
      class="words" data-start="41.03" data-dur="1.58">technologies, called
      spinoffs,</span> <span class="words" data-start="42.61" data-dur="4.36">help
      doctors heal patients with heart problems, scientists track rare
      animals, and</span> <span class="words" data-start="46.97" data-dur="2.409">firefighters
      and police officers and soldiers</span> <span class="words" data-start="49.379"
      data-dur="4.45">stay safe on the job. Space technology has even helped
      Olympic swimmers win</span> <span class="words" data-start="53.829" data-dur="0.711">gold
      medals.</span> <span class="words" data-start="54.54" data-dur="3.63">All
      of these the spinoffs began as innovations for nasa missions</span> <span
      class="words" data-start="58.17" data-dur="3.86">like the space
      shuttle, the Hubble Space Telescope, and the International Space</span>
    <span class="words" data-start="62.03" data-dur="3.18">Station. You
      don't have to be an astronaut to trace</span> <span class="words" data-start="65.21"
      data-dur="3.47">space back to where you live. Visit nasa.gov</span> <span
      class="words" data-start="68.68" data-dur="3.549">to learn more about
      how nasa technologies play a role in your life.</span> <span class="words"
      data-start="72.229" data-dur="3.331">After all, there's no space like
      home</span> </div>
</div>
```

The video just sends me back to 10 seconds regardless which span I click on. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo you can use as a template - http://demo.jwplayer.com/iframes/interactive-transcript/